# Ember.js render template before data loads

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

currently i'm working with ember rc-1 and ember-data rev-11.

I would like to know if it is posible to render parent's route template before getting ajax success from child route.

I have a router:

```
-index
      -objects
```

template for index:

```
<!-- some html that i would like to display on page load event -->
{{outlet}}
```

template for objects:

```
{{#each item in controller }}
<!-- data from item -->
{{/each}}
```

Objects route model method:

```
model: function(){
    return App.Object.find({limit: 0}) //this request is really heavy for backend and takes a lot of time
}
```

So when i navigate to objects url i see a blank page until i get response from server with all objects.

Maybe i'm front but it worked perfectly well in ember pre2 or pre-3. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default if you pass a query to `model.find` it will return a promise. And if your route's model hook returns a promise the ember router enters loading state and waits for promises to be resolved.

If instead you use App.Object.find(), ember returns a live-query with no promise. If it's the first time a find has been called for a model, store will it kick off an async query with no params to load initial dataset.

> Any ideas?

Ideally would be great if you can get rid of {limit: 0} param. Otherwise, consider setting model from setupController hook:

```
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('content', App.Object.find({limit: 0}));
  }
});
```